# On graph homomorphism properties

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G,H$ be finite graphs with $|V(H)| > |V(G)|$.

Let $\mathcal{f}:G\rightarrow H$ be an injective homomorphism - that is, $\mathcal{f}$ is:

$1.$ Injective - $\mathcal{f}(g_1)\neq\mathcal{f}(g_2)$, $\forall g_i\in V(H)$.

$2.$ Homomorphic - $g_1g_2\in E(G)\implies \mathcal{f}(g_1)\mathcal{f}(g_2)\in E(H)$.

Let $\odot$ imply one of the graph products:

$1.$ Tensor

$2.$ Cartesian

$3.$ Strong

$f \odot f:G \odot G \rightarrow H\odot H$ is injective.

Is $f \odot f:G \odot G \rightarrow H\odot H$ a homomorphism?

Is there a reference for this fact?